# sendDevToolsCommand in Selenium 4 alpha

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, devtools

According to this [article](https://medium.com/@4400vijay/selenium-4-alpha-is-released-whats-new-7fce5e8cd926), Selenium 4 alpha has a `sendDevToolsCommand` that sends an arbitrary DevTools command to the browser and returns a promise that will be resolved when the command has finished:

> Added “sendDevToolsCommand” and “setDownloadPath” for chrome.Driver.

But I can't seem to find how to use it. It sounds a bit like using JavaScript executor in Selenium.

Can someone provide an example usage? I'm using Selenium + Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command to call the devtool api was added a few years back in the Chrome driver.

You can already use it with Selenium even if the method is not yet present:

- [Take full page screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45201692/2887618)
- [Print To PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47024291/2887618)
- [Inject some Javascript before the page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47298910/2887618)
- [Block a network URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46891301/can-i-automate-chrome-request-blocking-using-selenium-webdriver-for-**ruby**/46894930#46894930)
- [Save/restore the cookies for all domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47020772/selenium-and-google-how-do-you-use-cookies/47022711#47022711)
- [Get transparent screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46656622/transparent-screenshot-with-headless-chromedriver-via-selenium/46755537#46755537)

This command gives you access to the [devtools api](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/), which is used by ChromeDriver internally to drive the browser.

The method takes the name of the command as first argument and a dictionary of parameters as second argument. To figure out how to call a command, add `puppeteer` in your searches. For instance [puppeteer set download location](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=puppeteer+set+download+location).

Note that [executeCdpCommand](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/aa546c58a0147f80b28fa5deda65ef0b2279151d/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/chromium/ChromiumDriver.java#L143) is implemented in the Java master branch, so it should be available in the next release.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find the `sendDevToolsCommand` in the Selenium documentation yet, but the [source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/379f6b4612843475a6e3c68b3bc43ed75a97fe74/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js#L765-L779) actually has the `setDownloadPath` that you also mentioned above [defined right below](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/379f6b4612843475a6e3c68b3bc43ed75a97fe74/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js#L781-L802), which actually uses the `sendDevToolsCommand`. Based on that usage, it seems like you could do something like:

```
const { Builder } = require("selenium-webdriver");

const driverInstance = await new Builder()
  .withCapabilities({ browserName: "chrome" })
  .build();

driverInstance.sendDevToolsCommand('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
  behavior: 'allow',
  downloadPath: path
})
```

or for a visually obvious example:

```
await driverInstance.sendDevToolsCommand("Emulation.setDefaultBackgroundColorOverride", {
  color: { r: 0, g: 255, b: 0, a: 1 } // watch out, it's bright!
});
```

where the first argument is a [Chrome Devtools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) Domain method (e.g. or [`Page.setDownloadBehavior`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page#method-setDownloadBehavior) or [`Emulation.setCPUThrottlingRate`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Emulation#method-setCPUThrottlingRate)) and the second argument is an object containing the options for that Domain method (as described in the same protocol docs).

Edit: just tested and the above works :)

I'm excited that this was added because it means that, in addition to network throttling, it should be pretty trivial to add cpu throttling to Selenium tests now! Something like:

```
driverInstance.sendDevToolsCommand('Emulation.setCPUThrottlingRate', {
  rate: 4 // throttle cpu 4x
}
```

Comment: This is great, but this is JS code. I would like to see how can I use this in tests written in Selenium + Java.

Comment: Hi @apeltz could you please share this code on gitHub?

Answer (score 4):

Selenium 4 release will have a user friendly API for Chrome DevTools protocol.
I just finished implementing Network and Performance domains for the Selenium Java client.
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/7212

In addition, there is a generic API for all domains in Java client that was merged a while ago.
All those new features will be released probably in the next Alpha release.

Comment: Great work on [Dev tools Network and Performance](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/7212)