# Capture network requests using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In the chrome dev tools, there is an option to capture network requests.
I would like to know if there is any way to access the requests using selenium, in python.

I have searched this topic, But I could not find a solution. Solutions with other libraries are also appriciated!

Requests screenshot:
[image: devtools screenshot]

Specific request info:
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure Selenium does not offer a feature like this. Look into PlayWright.

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56165801/senddevtoolscommand-in-selenium-4-alpha.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium 4 implements Chrome Dev Tools protocol support. However, it is still in alpha version, so keep that in mind if you intend to use it in the production code.

Here are some example usages from [Automate the Planet](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/selenium-webdriver-4-overview) that you might find helpful:

### **1. Intercepting Requests**

```
EventHandler<RequestInterceptedEventArgs> requestIntercepted = (sender, e) =>
{
    Assert.IsTrue(e.Request.Url.EndsWith("jpg"));
};
            
RequestPattern requestPattern = new RequestPattern();
requestPattern.InterceptionStage = InterceptionStage.HeadersReceived;
requestPattern.ResourceType = ResourceType.Image;
requestPattern.UrlPattern = "*.jpg";
var setRequestInterceptionCommandSettings = new SetRequestInterceptionCommandSettings();
setRequestInterceptionCommandSettings.Patterns = new RequestPattern[] { requestPattern };
devToolssession.Network.SetRequestInterception(setRequestInterceptionCommandSettings);
devToolssession.Network.RequestIntercepted += requestIntercepted;
```

### **2. Listen to Console Logs**

```
EventHandler<MessageAddedEventArgs> messageAdded = (sender, e) =>
{
    Assert.AreEqual("BELLATRIX is cool", e.Message);
};
devToolssession.Console.Enable();
devToolssession.Console.ClearMessages();
devToolssession.Console.MessageAdded += messageAdded;
_driver.ExecuteScript("console.log('BELLATRIX is cool');");
```

NOTE: This is Java implementation, you should edit it for Python.

Comment: For __Python__ you can use [Selenium-interceptor](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/selenium_interceptor#change-headers)